# changing data in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a column of integer values between 0 and 4 with these values :

```
0    108286
1      2042
2       183
3        13
4         3
```

I want to replace all non zero values with one
I tried the following code:

```
def to_bool(array):
    for index, value in enumerate(array):
        if value !=0:
            array[index] = 1
to_bool(df.handcap)
```

with expected output:

```
0    108286
1      2241
```

but after running the function I got:

```
0    107690
1      2817
2        16
3         2
4         1
```

what's the problem there? and how can I convert all of them to either 0 or 1?

Comment: Your approach should've also worked. Can you replicate it and share a python fiddle?

Comment: How 2042 become 2241?

Comment: the column is something like 1,0,4,3,2,0,0,1....(commas represent rows) i used"value_counts()" for that output so i want to end up with only zeros and ones(by replaceing all non zero values with 1)

Comment: @MarcoNashaat `df['your_column'].gt(0).astype(int).value_counts()` should do it. `your_column` is the column you mentioned in previous comment i.e. `the column is something like 1,0,4,3,2,0,0,1`

Answer (score 0):

Convert all non zero index values to 1 and sum each group (0 and 1):

```
>>> df.groupby(df.index.astype(bool).astype(int)).sum()
   handcap
0   108286
1     2241

# OR

>>> df.groupby((df.index != 0).astype(int)).sum()
   handcap
0   108286
1     2241
```

Comment: i want to change the values (1,2,3,4) in the column all to 1 and keep the 0 values as it is!...sorry for your troubles!

Comment: the columns is something like 0,1,4,0,2,3,4,1..... so i want to convert the non zero values to 1......the commas represent rows

Comment: @MarcoNashaat. Please consider to accept the answer if this suits to your need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please check this

```
for i in range(1,4):    
  df.rename(index={i:1}, inplace=True)
df_new = df.groupby( level = 0 , as_index=False).agg(np.sum)
```

Comment: @MarcoNashaat. Does this query solve your problem bro?